# How to compute value for InputSlider R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm doing a Shiny app and I have a question. I want to have a slider input which min and max values depends on values in some dataframe. That's easy to make. But I want the value of slider input to be mean of those min and max values in input and don't know how to data. I don't know if anyone will understand but maybe code will help. 
ui.R

```
sliderInput("param1", "Param1", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0, step = 0.01),
```

server.R

```
observeEvent( updateSliderInput(inputId = "param1", min = ... //getting the value from df,
                          max = ... //getting the value from df,
                          value = input$param1$min + (input$param1$max - input$param1$min/2)) //that's what I want to do but it's not working
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any reproducible demo and error information, I can only tell you what I found wrong.

The value argument in `updateSliderInput()` need to be *The initial value of the slider, either a number, a date (class Date), or a date-time (class POSIXt). A length one vector will create a regular slider; a length two vector will create a double-ended range slider. **Must lie between min and max**.*.

In your case, the value is equal to `input$param1$min/2 + input$param1$max`, which is greater than `input$param1$max`.

**Update**

Based on the code you provided, I would like to mention several things.

1. `shinyUI()` and `shinyServer()` are superseded in the current version of Shiny. Although it doesn't generate any error, I would suggest you to not use them.
2. To use `updateSliderInput()`, you need input updater functions send a message to the client. Therefore, you should combine `updateSliderInput()` with some functions like `observe()` or `observeEvent()`.
3. The value generated from the double-ended range slider is a vector of length two. You should use `input$param1[1]` instead of `input$param1$min`.
4. There's some reactivity problem in your code. I would suggest you to understand how shiny update the value. [This link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) may be useful for this part.

I'm not very sure about what you want, but I would put what I understand you want below.

```
ui = fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Title",              
             tabPanel("Section1", 
                      div("text"), 
             ),              
             tabPanel(
               "Section2", 
               sidebarPanel(
                 sliderInput(inputId = "param1", 
                             label = "SlideBar", 
                             min = min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                             max = max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                             value = min(iris$Sepal.Length)/2 + max(iris$Sepal.Length)/2), 
                 actionButton("submit", "Submit")
               ),
               mainPanel(h1('Text'))
             ) 
  )
)

server = function(input, output) { 
  observe({
    print(input$param1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's actually `input$param1$min + (input$param1$max - input$param1$min)/2`, I've made a mistake. So it's the mean of min and max. I have a regular slider with one value.

Comment: @Alexandra so did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, it's the same. There is no error occuring, the slider just gets value equal to minimum possible.

Comment: Could you provide a demo so I can look inside? You could also try to debug your code as shown in https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#debugging

Comment: ui.R
`shinyUI(fluidPage( 
  navbarPage(title = "Title",
             tabPanel("Section1",                   
                      div('text"),
             ),
             tabPanel("Section2",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput("param1", label = "Param1",
                                    min = 0, max = 1, value = 0, step = 0.01),
                        actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        h1('Text')
                      )
             )
  )
))`

Comment: server.R
`shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    updateSliderInput(inputId = "param1", 
                      min = 7, //change because there's interaction with database
                      max = 17,
                      value = input$param1$min + (input$param1$max - input$param1$min)/2)
})`

Comment: Hi @Alexandra, the code you've provided has some issue. I'll post my finding in my answer as it's easier to read.